# Response' object is not subscriptable Python http post request

Tags: python, json, post, request

I am trying to post a `HTTP` request. I have managed to get the code to work but I am struggling returning some of the result.

The result looks like this

```
{
  "requestId" : "8317cgs1e1-36hd42-43h6be-br34r2-c70a6ege3fs5sbh",
  "numberOfRequests" : 1893
}
```

I am trying to get the requestId but I keep getting the error Response' object is not subscriptable

```
import json
import requests

workingFile = 'D:\\test.json'

with open(workingFile, 'r') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

url = 'http://jsontest'
username = 'user'
password = 'password123'

requestpost = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(username, password))

print(requestpost["requestId"])
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The `response` object contains much more information than just the payload. To get the JSON data returned by the POST request, you'll have to access `response.json()` as described [in the example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
requestpost = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(username, password))
response_data = requestpost.json()
print(response_data["requestId"])
```

Answer (score 11):

You should convert your response to a dict:

```
requestpost = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(username, password))
res = requestpost.json()
print(res["requestId"])
```

Answer (score 1):

the response is not readable so you need to convert that into a readable format,
I was using python **http.client**

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('localhost', 5000)

payload = json.dumps({'username': "username", 'password': "password"})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
conn.request('POST', '/api/user/register', payload, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print("JSON - ", response.read())
```

and for request, you can see the answers above

sometimes you have to use `json.loads()` function to convert the appropriate format.