# Python - HTTP POST 'Response' object is not subscript-able

Tags: python, flask, http-post

I have below code in Python3 that receives a POST request. Example request shown later.

I see that the POST request is coming properly. The JSON data that comes through POST has 2 keys- `"id"` and `"ingredients"`. But when I try to access the data based on the keys for example content["id"] like below, it shows error

> TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Code:

```
@app.route('/cuisine/api/json',methods=['POST'])
def getCuisine():
    content = jsonify(request.json)
    return content["id"]
```

Example CURL

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request POST   --data '{"id": 10259,"ingredients": ["romaine lettuce","black olives","grape tomatoes","garlic","pepper","purple onion","seasoning","garbanzo beans","feta cheese crumbles"]}'   http://127.0.0.1:5000/cuisine/api/json
```

I think I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508981/response-object-is-not-subscriptable-python-http-post-request) properly but doesn't work. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Full error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/MacUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/MacUser/Desktop/cuisine-prediction/webservice.py", line 62, in getCuisine
    return content["id"]
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. please see the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jsonify` converts a Python object to a Flask response with a JSON payload. So you're taking the parsed data (which is a Python dict) from the request and converting it back to JSON. You should be using `request.json` directly to get your data.

```
@app.route('/cuisine/api/json',methods=['POST'])
def getCuisine():
    return jsonify(request.json["id"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t call `jsonify` on request.json and then use that object as a dictionary. Calling `request.json` will try and return a dictionary from the JSON.

So do your steps backwards like:

`return jsonify(request.json.get(‘id’))`

But the real reason to your problem is `jsonify` creates an HTTP Response object which is not the simple dictionary you’re thinking it is.