# TypeError: 'Post' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently trying to figure out why I can't extract specific keys/values from the returned dict. Looking this issue up I found [this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508981/response-object-is-not-subscriptable-python-http-post-request) question basically stating that the object needs to be in json format in order to be accessed.

```
def Dumpster_Fire_Parser():

    import moesearch
    import pandas as pd

    trash = moesearch.search(archiver_url="https://archive.4plebs.org",
                             board="pol",
                             filter="image",
                             deleted="not-deleted",
                             )
    # trash = dict(trash)

    time_dumpster_dict = {}
    country_dumpster_dict = {}

    for i, j in enumerate(trash):

        trash_dict = j
        time_stamp = trash_dict['timestamp']
        comment = trash_dict['comment']
        country = trash_dict['poster_country_name']
        time_dumpster_dict[time_stamp] = comment
        country_dumpster_dict[time_stamp] = country

    export_frame = pd.DataFrame([time_dumpster_dict, country_dumpster_dict]).T
    export_frame.columns = ['d{}'.format(i) for i, col in enumerate(export_frame, 1)]

    print(export_frame)

    return export_frame
```

Running this code returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 17, in <module>
TypeError: 'Post' object is not subscriptable
```

I looked through the source code for `moesearch.search()` and its already converted to a json object there.

```
req = requests.get(url, stream=False, verify=True, params=kwargs)
  res = req.json() # How its written in source
```

I tried explicitly casting it as a dict once the request is complete via `trash = dict(trash)` however that returns another error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence 
# Is thrown when trash = dict(trash) isn't commented out
```

Anyone run into this before? This code is executable, keep in mind Search API is limited to 5 requests per minute. Other end points aren't limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the source code for `moesearch` convertes to JSON in [Line 40](https://github.com/alfateam123/moesearch/blob/master/moesearch/api.py#L40), but a few lines further down you can see that the function `search()` returns a list of `Post` objects ([line 44](https://github.com/alfateam123/moesearch/blob/master/moesearch/api.py#L44), the `return` statement):

```
def search(archiver_url, board, **kwargs):
    ...
    req = requests.get(url, stream=False, verify=True, params=kwargs)
    res = req.json()
    if ArchiveException.is_error(res):
        raise ArchiveException(res)
    res = res['0']
    return [Post(post_obj) for post_obj in res["posts"]]
```

So in your code, `trash` is a list and `j` is an object of type `Post`; you can check that like this:

```
trash = moesearch.search(...)
print(type(trash))
print(trash)

for i, j in enumerate(trash):
    print(type(j))
    ...
```

Comment: Gotcha, so iterating through the `Post()` object is basically like iterating through a list of dicts?

Comment: @SebastianGoslin I am not sure; you will have to read the definition of the [`Post` class](https://github.com/alfateam123/moesearch/blob/master/moesearch/parser.py#L15)